# Setting a ReadOnly TextBox default BackColor

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, textbox

I have a `TextBox` which is set to be `ReadOnly`.
At some point that `TextBox` is being available for editing, and it's `BackColor` changes (It is indicating if the value is valid).
If I want to set the `TexBox` back to `ReadOnly`, the `TextBox` doesn't get back the original `BackColor` that a `ReadOnly` `TextBox` gets.
What should I do in order to get the original color again?
I realize I can set the color manually to `SystemColors.Control`, but is this the "right way"?

### Code Sample

This is a simple code for demonstration.
If `SystemColors.Control` is the way to go, I will change it in the `ReadOnlyChanged` event...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //At this point this.textBox1 is ReadOnly
    this.textBox1.ReadOnly = false;
    this.textBox1.BackColor = Color.Orange;


    /*this.textBox1.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;*/ //Is this the right way?
    this.textBox1.ReadOnly = true; //Textbox remains orange...
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to set `BackColor` to the look of a `ReadOnly TextBox's BackColor`, that is `Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control)`:

```
//this is the ReadOnlyChanged event handler for your textbox
private void textBox1_ReadOnlyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
   if(textBox1.ReadOnly) textBox1.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control);
}
```

You may need a variable to store the current BackColor every time your TextBox's BackColor changes:

```
Color currentBackColor;
bool suppressBackColorChanged;
private void textBox1_BackColorChanged(object sender,EventArgs e){
   if(suppressBackColorChanged) return;
   currentBackColor = textBox1.BackColor;
}
private void textBox1_ReadOnlyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
   suppressBackColorChanged = true;
   textBox1.BackColor = textBox1.ReadOnly ? Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control) : currentBackColor;
   suppressBackColorChanged = false;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but for posterity sake:

TextBox as well as many other controls rely on Color.Empty to decide whether or not to display its default color.

To set a TextBox back to the system default (irregardless of state):

```
textBox1.BackColor = Color.Empty;
```

Comment: On the same note, setting a non-empty backcolor will also make a custom **fore**color actually show.

Comment: upvote - even though you used 'irregardless' ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's fine. There's no reason you can't use the SystemColors to specify the desired color for the control. I've never heard of anything in `WinForms` that would cause a control to automatically revert to its default color upon setting `ReadOnly = true`.

I suppose one alternative is to create a class-level variable called `textBox1OriginalColor` or something and set it in the form's `Load` event. Then you know exactly what it was when the form was originally displayed, if you think someone might in the future set the text box's default background color to, say, blue in the designer or something.