# How do I set the background color of a readonly textbox in Winforms?

Tags: winforms

I have several textboxes in a Winforms window.
These textboxes need to be set to readonly in the design.
(I don't want to use labels, because some of these are multiline).

I would like to keep the original background color and not display the "disabled" grey color for the background.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a read only Textbox default Backcolor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039901/setting-a-read-only-textbox-default-backcolor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Background property of the control.